# One arm won't fold after some reps while doing bicep dumbbell curls

Tags: muscle, dumbbells, biceps

Currently I am a beginner in muscle building and to train my bicep muscles I am using dumbbells and I am performing dumbbell curls with them.

While performing the curls, after some reps my left arm wont fold completely and gets stuck in middle of the way, while the opposite arm folds completely. Due to this I have to use my shoulder muscle to make it fold, and which moves the tension from the bicep muscle to the shoulder.

What can be the reason behind it and is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: Is the arm that is not completing your weak arm? If so, and you can perform complete reps with good form before, you are "failing" a rep. Which is not bad in itself. Also, how many reps can you make with this arm? You shouldn't complete the rep with the shoulder as that defeats the purpose of the exercise. You should stop doing reps at that point, or use a lighter weight to get more reps in.

Comment: Yes, it is my weak arm. I am able to complete 1 set of 10-12 reps with this arm, but after taking a 1 minute break and performing few reps in the second set, the arm stops folding after halfway.

Comment: 10/12 reps is fine, take a 3/5 minute break between sets and then finish wherever you finish on the second set. That is more than enough to start. You'll see progress if you start increasing the weight slowly.

There is this idea of strength training that you should train until failure (or near failure) which is where adaptations happen.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the suggestion ParibusCeteris

Comment: You need to lower the weight and make sure both arms can complete the set. Don't increase the weight until your weak arm catches up either. Also always start with your weak arm, if you notice yourself failing short a rep, then skip a rep on your strong arm. Try doing alternate curls as well so you can focus on each arm and stop your strong arm from doing more.